# Downloaded Eclipse Mars 1 checksums don't match

Tags: eclipse, wget

I downloaded Eclipse Mars 1 from a mirror chosen for me on the Eclipse website. But the `md5sum` on the downloaded file is `929f821dc83eaac83fc6320b291dcb7f` while on the Eclipse website it's been given as `72a722a59a43e8ed6c47ae279fb3d355`. This struck me as odd because it's the first time I'm experiencing something like this -- I've made like ~20 such downloads, different files, different servers, since I started learning how to code -- and all of them matched the checksums on their respective servers.

So I decided to get a fresh download from a different mirror. I chose https://spring.io/tools/eclipse. And the thing is, I can't find any checksums around there but the `md5sum` for their file is `a562f87ddf353dd8519edfc072d4c67d`. I'm confused. I'm under the impression that irregardless of the mirror, the file hash should match the hash given on the Eclipse website -- `72a722a59a43e8ed6c47ae279fb3d355`

Answer (score 0):

Either the `md5sum` was not updated correctly on the website or you had a hiccup in your Internet connection that made the file change, resulting in the difference  you're having.

Another rare case might be that you made a mistake in choosing the checking 
option: for example I once copied the `sha1` code instead of `md5`.